# POST information doesn't appear when using javascript to auto POST a form

Tags: javascript, html, post

I'm using this script to automatically POST a form:

```
<form method='post' id='redirect' action='https://example.php'>
        <input type='hidden' value='<?php echo $r_username; ?>' name='r_username'>
        <input type='submit' value='Submit' name='redirect_search_user_submit' id='redirect_search_user_submit'>
</form>
<script type="text/javascript">
        setTimeout(function(){
            document.getElementById('redirect').submit(); // SUBMIT FORM
      }, 5000);
</script>
```

The script POST just fine, but none of the POST information goes with it. If I leave out the automatic POST script, everything works fine. How can I get the POST information to go along with the automatic POST?

Comment: What do you mean redirect script?

Comment: @Carprog I meant to say automatic POST script. I corrected it.

Comment: I have run the code and it seems to work. Is the problem in the receiving script? (also is the action correct? That url I think will not work.)

Comment: @Catprog I changed the url for this post. You received all the POST information from the form? It only works for me if I take out the code between the <script> tags.

Comment: Yes I received all the post information. Prehaps you could post your example.php code as well?

Comment: @Catprog Maybe the problem is that I'm doing it within an iframe. I'll look into it later.